# Adding UICollectionView inside UIView without Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have ViewController called **myVC** with UITablewView - **myTable**.

What I want is to add some UIView as **myTable's** headerView ***from code***. So inside viewDidLoad() method of **myVC** I added this code

```
    let topView = TopView()
    topView.frame.size.height = 100
    topView.frame.size.width = myTable.frame.width
    myTable.tableHeaderView = featuredEventsView
```

I also created file called TopView.swift that looks something like

```
class TopView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)            
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {.....}
}
```

And it is working as it should. I see red UIView in headerView of **myTable**.

Now I want to add UICollectionView inside **topView** and I have problems here. I am trying to do something like

```
class TopView : UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)            
        self.backgroundColor = .red

        addSubview(myCollectionView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {.....}

let myCollectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let cv = UICollectionView()
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.delegate = self as! UICollectionViewDelegate
        cv.dataSource = self as! UICollectionViewDataSource
        cv.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return cv
    }()
}
```

I also created functions needed to UICollectionViewDataSource but app crashes after building. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"app crashes after building"* ... Error message(s)? Have you stepped through in debug to find out where exactly it's causing a crash?

Comment: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" - this is all I can see - how can I get more?

Comment: Set a debug breakpoint, and step through line by line until you find the exact code that is causing the crash.

Comment: Ok, it crashes after let topView = TopView()

Comment: What is the line of code after that? Or do you mean it crashes *inside* that line? Like perhaps in `TopView init`? If so, on which line in there? And you *must* be getting more of an error than you show here... Do you have the debug console pane open? Is there really **nothing** other than *"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"*?

Comment: Yes, it all i see inside debug pane. By setting breakpoints - I find that it is crashing after let cv = UICollectionView() in TopView.swift

Comment: Is `UICollectionView()` a valid way to create a collection view instance? I'm pretty sure you need to provide a frame and a UICollectionViewLayout...

Comment: in that case - how should I init it properly?

Comment: I'd suggest first searching for `uicollectionview programmatically swift` and going through a tutorial or two. When you've got a handle on that part, then you can work on adding it in to another class as you're trying to do here.

Comment: can you show an image what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1) You initialise your UICollectionView incorrectly as you must give it a layout.  You need something like this (use whatever frame you want but if you are going on to use auto layout it doesn't matter):

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

2) You cannot reference 'self' inside the closure when initialising a property.  This is because if may not have been initialised (as in this case) so you can't guarantee it's safe to use it.

I think you should be ok if you use lazy initialisation like this (plus you don't even need to cast 'self'):

```
lazy var myCollectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.backgroundColor = .yellow
    return cv
}()
```

Using the lazy method should delay until self is initialised and therefore safe to use.